# find if 2 cells match and replace the text from 1 of them

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large dump of data that needs to have text replaced if 2 specific cells match. I am looking for a formula or clickable option so I can record this as a macro.

example text;

**Area    Location**
MP          AA
MP          AB
MP          AC
MP          AD

This list has several hundred values for each of the area and location combinations. I need to find any Location that is marked **AD** and replace the text in the cell to the left from **MP** to **SEC**.
Been scratching my head for several hours and cannot even get close to a result.

Comment: Put a filter on it, select "AD" for the Location and put what you want in the Area? Safer than running an automated process as you can review the list before selecting as needed and pasting an update in. Not really seeing the need for a macro - unless you have a large list of various replacements.

Comment: @Joffan cannot unfortunately. the list shrinks and grows each day. I have a macro for a large cleanup that works quite well. just looking for that final step by replacing the MP for the AD location

Answer (score 0):

If Column A is Area and Column B is Location, why not just `=IF($B1="AD", "SEC", $A1)`?

Answer (score 0):

This macro makes the substitution you talk about above, starting under the Location header and stopping at the first empty cell below that. It's written so that you can put in the appropriate cell address where the "Location" and "Area" headers are.

```
Sub SwapMPtoSECinAD()

Dim AreaCell As Range
Dim LocCell As Range
Dim ColDiff As Long

Set AreaCell = Range("A1") ' <-- Area header cell
Set LocCell = Range("B1") ' <-- Location header cell
ColDiff = AreaCell.Column - LocCell.Column

Set LocCell = LocCell.Offset(1, 0)
While Not IsEmpty(LocCell)
    If Trim(LocCell.Text) = "AD" Then
        If Trim(LocCell.Offset(0, ColDiff).Text) = "MP" Then _
                    LocCell.Offset(0, ColDiff).Value = "SEC"
    End If
    Set LocCell = LocCell.Offset(1, 0)
Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

So you just need to replace MP|AD to MP|SEC

```
=IF((AND(A5>="MP", B5>="AD")), "SEC", A5)
```

Anyway theres your 2 conditions to match.

Pull a column right and drag. Then Copy and Paste in place in location.

Comment: Greater than does not belong in the formula